# Html.Partial ( ) is not working with _grid.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcgrid

i have a web application developed in MVC 3 using VS2010. But when i open it through VS 2013 i am shown the following error.

```
    System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 
   'Partial' and no extension method 'Partial' accepting a first argument of type  
   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using
    directive or an assembly reference?
```

And i now VS 2010 is also showing the same error. what to do? Plz help me out..

Comment: are you sure you have a reference to `System.Web.Mvc.dll` from your project?

Comment: no, sorry. it worked after adding the reference. Thanx a lot @Selman22

Comment: But its working for some time. How to add the reference permanently

Answer (score 0):

add this namespace and see if it helps

System.Web.Mvc.Html

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution check the link it will be of better help

[warnings - html.helpers not recognized after project update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791890/warnings-html-helpers-not-recognized-after-project-update)

the person experienced the same problem read through it,your problem is bullet 4  and good luck

like tommy said ">>>**The assembly versions need to match what you have upgraded to**<<<. Also, after making these changes, you may need to do a **clean/rebuild in VS to ensure you have cleared the old assemblies out."**

Comment: swagat this is the solution take it or leave it my friend and good luck to you

Comment: But its showing me the following error.
**Error 11 Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is "3.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "1.0.0.0". To continue, remove files from the application's bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config.**

Comment: did you rebuild your application after the change and type in the version you upgraded to

Comment: the oak had the exact problem that you are experiencing swag bullet 4 i believe it should work for you too

Comment: No its Not working. My application is running fine, but each time i build my solution i ma shown that message again and again. And Html.Partial() is working fine in other pages..