# ASP.NET MVC 5 Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm working on a project which is using mvc 5,ef 6.1, visual studio 2013. First i start coding from admin panel after its done i get back to admin panel for some changes.

Then i got those errors : http://prntscr.com/34tuby

ViewBag, Html Helper is not recognizing.

Project can compiling and working but when open a cshtml (view) file in visual studio i got those error.

for solution i tried;

- Clean/Rebuild Project
- Compare web.configs
- Compare View web.configs
- Compare project properties
- Compare packages config

all packages same, web.config files same , all packages version same with working project.

-Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code for the view?

Comment: like that ? http://prntscr.com/34u18x, http://prntscr.com/34u1hl

Comment: Perhaps this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725514/one-or-more-types-required-to-compile-a-dynamic-expression-cannot-be-found-are

Comment: References same with other projects

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your configuration file, as mentioned in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791890/warnings-html-helpers-not-recognized-after-project-update).  It's usually related to config entries not matching the correct DLL's.

Comment: i check it, its same.

Answer (score 0):

I create new project and transfer all files with same namespace. And it work